# Installing Ubuntu on asus q200e-bhi3t45

Tags: installation, asus

Can someone give me the step by step info on the correct way to install Ubuntu on a asus q200e-bhi3t45 notebook? That I will not get a ton of errors or Ubuntu will run slow?

Comment: To begin with you have to disable Secure Boot in the Bios, this can be a tricky. After that everything worked out of the box, even the touchscreen and in the Live session (Ubuntu 13.04)

Answer (score 1):

> That I will not get a ton of errors or Ubuntu will run slow?

How do we find out?

Well simple:

download your version of Ubuntu (12.04.2 = what I advise, or 12.10) and make a bootable DVD or USB-stick (this you can do with Unetbootin on both Windows or Ubuntu) 
Set your Bios to boot the desired medium; DVD or stick. 
And follow the on-screen procedures.

You can test Ubuntu by selecting 'try Ubuntu' (this option will let you test-run Ubuntu and NOT install it) ; check if all your hardware is supported (e.g. Wifi-card/ CD-bay / etc)
If so all went well, you can be pretty shure that installing and using this operating system will go fine.

Things to mind: your graphic card is maybe a pain; download and use, if nessecary, additional drivers.

[for more information and how-to's click here !!](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I just installed ubuntu on my asus q200e (feeling proud). The following are the steps i took:

1. make a bootable usb disk
2. turn computer off and insert usb
3. turn on and press F2
4. go to "SECURITY" and turn disable "SECURITY (something) CONTROL"
5. go to the last tab and chose to boot using the usb
6. install and give yourself a pat on the back and send good juju my way